# WindowsAzure.Storage ошибка 404

Tags: c#, .net, map-reduce, azure

Почему мне сервер возвращает `404 ошибку`?

А именно:

> Исключение типа "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException" возникло в Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Класс `Constants.cs`, в котором содержаться константные значения, такие как информация о кластере, информация о хранилище и т.д.

```
  public class Constants
{
    public static Uri azureClusterUri = new Uri("https://AutomHDICluster.azurehdinsight.net:563");
    public static string thumbprint = "****";
    public static Guid subscriptionId = new Guid("***");
    public static string clusterName = "AutomHDICluster";
    public static string clusterUser = "***";
    public static string hadoopUser = "hdp";
    public static string clusterPassword = "***";
    public static string storageAccount = "resforhadoop.blob.core.windows.net";
    public static string storageAccountKey = "***";
    public static string container = "hadoopclientres";
    public static string wasbPath = "wasb://hadoopclientres@resforhadoop.blob.core.windows.net";
}
```

`RootJob class`, в котором содержится информация о входных данных и выходной папке.

```
class RootJob : HadoopJob<RootMapper>
{
    public override HadoopJobConfiguration Configure(ExecutorContext context)
    {
        var config = new HadoopJobConfiguration
        {
            InputPath = Constants.wasbPath + "/example/data/test.txt",
            OutputFolder = Constants.wasbPath + "/example/data/output"
        };

        return config;

    }
```

Функция `DoCustomMapReduce()`

```
public static void DoCustomMapReduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting MapReduce job. Log in remotely to your Name Node and check progress from JobTracker portal with the returned JobID...");
        IHadoop hadoop = Hadoop.Connect(Constants.azureClusterUri, Constants.clusterUser, Constants.hadoopUser, Constants.clusterPassword, Constants.storageAccount, Constants.storageAccountKey, Constants.container, true);

        var output = hadoop.MapReduceJob.ExecuteJob<RootJob>(); (здесь кидает исключение)

    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34087/discussion-on-question-by-romka-pm-windowsazure-storage--404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблем было несколько:

1) `Content type` для `OutputFolder` должен быть `application/octet-stream`. Для загрузки blob-объектов использовал [Azure Storage explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/).

2) Проблема с Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage. Нужно установить более раннюю версию. Ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481353/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-cloudblob-%D0%B2-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-blob/481356#481356).