# отсутствие класса CloudBlob в Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Как решить эту проблему, если наличие класса `CloudBlob` требует другой подключенный пакет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо подключить через NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/6.2.0

Comment: спасибо огромное за ссылку. Только в этом пакете тоже нет этого класса. Поставил этот `Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 4.4.0-preview -Pre`. проблема решилась.

Comment: Давайте Вы не будете пихать рекламу в сообщения?